# Difference between SSHA512 and SHA512

Tags: passwords, password-hashing

I am using SSHA512 to encrypt email user's passwords. Manually doing this works using doveadm from dovecot. But I can't seem to implement this in my mail client. I can, however, use SHA512.

Is SHA512 less secure than SSHA512?

Comment: After a quick search I found [this code](http://gurolerdogan.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssha-encryption-with-java.html) which shows you *how not* to implement the SSHA-512 algorithm in Java, but if you have any issues implementing it you can always ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is SHA512 less secure than SSHA512?

Hashing passwords plainly with SHA512 is indeed less secure than using SSHA512. But note that this doesn't imply that using [SSHA512](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes#Salting) is actually a good / secure method for hashing your passwords.

The reason for the inequality is simple:

$$\operatorname{SSHA512}(\text{pw},\text{salt})=\operatorname{SHA512}(\text{pw}\parallel \text{salt})\parallel \text{salt}$$

So as you can see it's a case of a *single* iteration of SHA-512 paired with some basic salting. Salting is a good thing as it (among other things) thwarts [rainbow-tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) but of course a modern GPU (like the [Tesla V100](https://gist.github.com/iam1980/808f696a14b0c42b26621a01f91a8b18) or with nearly the same speed the [RTX 2080 Ti](https://pastebin.com/3BJXhkPG)) achieves about 1.8GH/s *per card*. That is $1.8\cdot 10^9$ SHA512 evaluations *per second and per card*. Also note that for about 25 USD/hr you can rent *8* of these on AWS which gives you about 2.1 TH/USD, that is an attacker can try about $2\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000$ password hashes for a single US-Dollar. So if the user has any *even remotely weak* password, it's a matter of a few USD to break it.

The more modern approach is then to use Argon2 or bcrypt instead which perform *much* worse on GPUs.